# How to Enable iTerm Profile Shortcut Key cmd-ctrl-d key by Disabling Dictionary Lookup in macOS for iTerm?

Tags: keyboard, shortcut, iterm, keybindings

I've been trying to set up a specific shortcut key (`cmd-control-d`) in iTerm to trigger a profile action. However, this shortcut conflicts with macOS's default dictionary lookup feature. I'm looking for a way to disable the system-wide dictionary shortcut, so that iTerm can exclusively use the command-control-D shortcut for its defined action.

Is there a method to accomplish this without affecting the functionality of other applications?

Answer (score 0):

The only solution I've found to this so far is to disable the SYSTEM WIDE functionality from [this old post comment](https://superuser.com/questions/326223/how-do-i-disable-the-command-control-d-word-definition-keyboard-shortcut-in-os-x#comment619760_516247), which effectively still works in 2024 for macOS 14 Sonoma:

1. Start Terminal.app / iTerm.app.
2. Issue the command:

   ```
   defaults write com.apple.symbolichotkeys AppleSymbolicHotKeys -dict-add 70 '<dict><key>enabled</key><false/></dict>'
   ```
3. Reboot.

After the system reboots you'll find that iTerm is now able to utilize `cmd-control-d` to execute this - and as a bonus you'll have freed up this command for other apps.

Remember, this is a system-wide command and will disable it universally.

I might also suggest that we make feature requests to Apple so that they will finally free this and/or any other similar command combos that might find little use normally and be difficult to access without jumping through such hoops.

Some additional notes that might be helpful:

- This is a source of some discussion on this particular point: https://alexfedoseev.com/blog/post/fight-for-your-hotkeys
- The following old prep script shows this particular example along with some others that are not clear as to what they do: https://github.com/zenangst/OSX-Configuration/blob/master/osx_bootstrap.sh#L414
- This might somehow be useful, but it's not yet clear (I'm having problems eliminating the cmd-control-f binding presently for example and am still researching this): https://gist.github.com/stephancasas/74c4621e2492fb875f0f42778d432973
- Some discussion on these codes: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21878482/what-do-the-parameter-values-in-applesymbolichotkeys-plist-dict-represent